# Tracking file descriptor activity on Linux

Tags: linux, file, race-condition

I'm facing an issue where my epoll descriptor is getting closed from underneath me. It's a huge code base and I've tried to trace the activities on the descriptor in the code, but to no avail. Is there a way to track the activities on a file descriptor (on Linux) and generate a call trace leading upto the point?

Any other suggestions to track the offending piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strace`, for example `strace -p your_process_pid_here`.